# How to recover deleted Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I accidentally, deleted all my cloud function on the CLI, is there anyway to recover it? I tried searching Google Cloud Platform features to restore it but with no avail.

Comment: did u try checking your cloud function here? https://console.cloud.google.com/functions

Comment: I tried checking it but it says, 
Your free trial is waiting: activate now to get $300 credit to explore Google Cloud products. Learn more. If I paid $300 can I retrieve that code there?

Comment: No you can't i just created a temporary function and then deleted that function, it was also removed from that list, i think there's no way to recover your cloud function

Comment: Thank you for the response and effort, please post it as answer so I can accept it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can't recover the deleted cloud function. Created a temporary cloud function and deleted the function to check if deleted is showed in the list https://console.cloud.google.com/functions, but the function was removed from the list.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today.
Here is the solution I found.

***Explanation of the solution***

apparently, when one creates a function onRequest

function, all the code is uploaded, no matter if it is used or not.

For example:

we have 2 enpoints

GET products

GET history

when creating the cloud function for products, not only the products code is uploaded, but also the history code.

***Step by step***

then, what you need, is to download the source code, of one of the functions that you currently have active here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/functions

(clearly the function, for which you downloaded the source code, had to be uploaded when you had in your source code, the code you are looking for now)

1. select the function that meets this requirement
2. go to the "source" tab
3. download the zip file of the source code

now you only have to search in that file, the code of the function you are looking for.